# WaitOne(timeout) after exception

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm currently working on an application that reads dat from a socket.

I was curious, if I have a `readDone.WaitOne(600000)` with a larger than normal timeout, what happens if the `readDone.Set()` is never called in my `ReadCallBack` method due to an exception in the callback method?

Does it wait for the entire duration of the timeout or does it continue excecuting the main thread by handling the exception which is defined outside the `ReadcallBack`?

**EDIT**

Here is an example to explain what I mean:

```
        public void SendAndReceive(Message message)
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(this.host.Address);
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, this.host.Port);

            using (Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                connectDone.WaitOne(host.Timeout);

                message.State = MessageState.SENDING;
                Send(client, message.Request);

                if (sendDone.WaitOne(120000)) // TIMEOUT SET TO 2 MINUTE
                {
                    // Request sent successful. Now attempt to retrieve response.
                    message.State = MessageState.READING;
                    Receive(client);
                }
                else
                {
                    message.State = MessageState.SEND_ERROR;
                    message.ErrorMessage = "Timeout while sending request to socket.";
                }                    

                // Release the socket.
                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.ExceptionHandler(ex);
            message.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            message.State = MessageState.EXCEPTION;
        }
    }


    private void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        System.IO.MemoryStream dataStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        dataStream.WriteByte(1);
        dataStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        dataStream.WriteByte(3);

        client.BeginSend(dataStream.GetBuffer(), 0, dataStream.GetBuffer().Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            client.EndSend(ar);

            // Throw exception before .Set can is called
            throw new Exception("test");

            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

So to clarify:

sendDone.WaitOne(120000) is set to timeout after 2 minutes, which means, is .Set() is not called in 2 minutes the main thread will continue to execute. My question is, if there is and exception in the SendCallBack before it can call the .Set(), will the sendDone still hold up the main thread for 2minutes, or will it automatically jump to the try catch in SendAndReceive method?

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me. Why would you expect it not to wait for the full timeout?

Comment: Post code and we'll be better able to answer that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tested this, and if an exception is thrown the WaitOne() is cancelled.